# how to use parameterized queries in vb when using SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've got an error that says "Must declare scalar variable" when I parametize my query.  I am new in using SQL Server. And the version that I'm using is SQL Server 2012. Below is the code snippet:

```
   Protected Sub Main_Page
    Dim con as OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd as OleDbCommand
    Dim query as String

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=ARIES-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB")
    con.Open()
    query = "INSERT INTO Instructors(FirstName,LastName,Address,Contact_Number) VALUES (@fname,@lname,@address,@number)"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFirstName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLastName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", txtContact.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
    Response.Write(<script>alert('Success!')</script>)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Also, you should use the `using` statement for any object that implements the `IDisposable` interface. Other then that, your code seems like it should be working.

Comment: Any reason why do you use OleDb instead of the native SqlClient library? Usually this error means that one of your fields or your table is mispelled and wrongly considered a parameter.

Comment: But when I run my code, I've got the error that says, "Must declare scalar variable".. what would be the appropriate solution to that?

Comment: The reason why I use OleDb instead of the native SqlClient library is that I'm most familiar with the OleDb library instead of the SqlClient..

Comment: Nothing to learn just change OleDb with SQL ... add namespace and that's it. Your code will work.

Comment: And change the connectionstring....

Comment: One thing that you could try with OleDb is changing the parameters placeholders with a single question mark (?) This is the official way to setup the parameters with OleDb albeit I think that the Sql Server provider is able to read your query with the _@name_ pattern as well.

Comment: Pericles ... try to change the parameters (address,number) names like addr, c_number ... I remember the same error once and this fix worked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterize query to avoid SQL injection, so for best practice use a simple stored procedure with parameters, it's working fine.

Your C# code

```
  Protected Sub Main_Page()
        Dim con As OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=ARIES-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB")

        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("spSaveData", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFirstName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLastName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", txtContact.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
        Response.Write(<script>alert('Success!')</script>)

    End Sub
```

Your stored procedure code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSaveData
    @fname varchar(200),
    @lname varchar(200),
    @address varchar(300),
    @number int
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Instructors(FirstName, LastName, Address, Contact_Number) 
    VALUES (@fname, @lname, @address, @number)
END
```

Comment: you welcome , feel free to post question , and vote the answer if helpfull